# How do you provide TemplateExporter config options to Jupyter nbconvert?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I want to customize `nbconvert`'s output by providing additional [TemplateExporter](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html) config options such as `exclude_markdown` when converting `.ipynb` to `.py`. However, none of the configs I provide ever get recognized on Jupyter 4.1.0.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you update nbconvert ? check with `jupyter nbconvert --version`; this option is relatively recent (commit dates Mars 2017).

The version of Jupyter does not matter, it is just a metapackage, and 4.1.0 is *likely* the version of Jupyter Core, as [Jupyter latest is still 1.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jupyter).

Comment: Turns out nbconvert is it's own package that can be updated as well! `pip install nbconvert -U` did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was unclear; almost all of the Jupyter packages are different components that can be updated independently.